# Keep same row when new rows are inserted

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a CountA formula:

```
=COUNTA('0 Data Summary'!B10:B108)
```

and a macro that creates a new client data row in row 10 every time and all other client data shifts down by one row. It works fine but, when a new row is inserted in row 10 via macro (for a new client add) the formula changes to:

```
=COUNTA('0 Data Summary'!B11:B109)
```

I want it to keep the **`B10`** and not change to `B11`. The change to `109` is fine because I want it to remain within the range.

I tried putting in the dollar signs but it didn't work.

Comment: The only way I know to accomplish this is with the [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) like `=COUNTA(INDIRECT("'0 Data Summary'!B10:B108"))`.

Comment: Possible duplciate of [Stuck in excel formula calling data from another sheet without changing cell reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27527752/stuck-in-excel-formula-calling-data-from-another-sheet-without-changing-cell-ref/27528012#27528012).

Comment: Oh well. That would be (slightly) different then. :) `=COUNTA(INDIRECT("'0 Data Summary'!B10:B"&ROW(108:108)))`

Comment: You could use Index instead of volatile Indirect: `=COUNTA(INDEX(B:B,10):B108)`

Answer (score 2):

You can make the first reference always refer to the 10th row in column B by using Index, like

```
=COUNTA(INDEX('0 Data Summary'!B:B,10):'0 Data Summary'!B109)
```

Comment: +1 for using [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) to get away from the volatile [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to teylyn's answer, you could anchor the starting address in concrete
by making its address a text string:

```
=COUNTA(INDIRECT("'0 Data Summary'!B10"):'0 Data Summary'!B108)
```

and using the `INDIRECT()` function to de-reference that string
(i.e., to treat it as a cell address
and retrieve the contents of the identified cell).

Comment: Keep in mind that Indirect is volatile and will cause a complete recalc of the worksheet when any cell is changed. Volatile functions can cause slowness with large workbooks.